# Error adding Tensorflow to PATH in POP!_os (which is similar to Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, since I'm very new to POP!_os and Linux in general. I want to install TensorFlow to my Pycharm IDE, but got a very long error message telling me to add a bunch of directories to PATH. I got this error after running `pip install TensorFlow-gpu`  .

```
    WARNING: The scripts pyrsa-decrypt, pyrsa-encrypt, pyrsa-keygen, pyrsa-priv2pub, pyrsa-sign and pyrsa-verify are installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script markdown_py is installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script google-oauthlib-tool is installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script tensorboard is installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts estimator_ckpt_converter, import_pb_to_tensorboard, saved_model_cli, tensorboard, tf_upgrade_v2, tflite_convert, toco and toco_from_protos are installed in '/home/trkornman/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I would like to know if there is a command for this, or if I have to move them manually, and if so, where I can find PATH in my file explorer.

Comment: Could you add the exact error message to the question?

Comment: @blazej it doesn't fit though, but I added it

Comment: never mind, it does now haha

Comment: Can you do an `echo $PATH` from your terminal?

Comment: `echo $PATH
/Users/trkornman/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
trkornman@pop-os:~$ `

Comment: This `/Users/trkornman/Library/Python/3.8/bin` looks like a macOS path how dit it get there?. Check my answer below.

Comment: Idk, I'm using virtualbox to run pop_os, so that could be it, but thats from a windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH`. You can do it by setting the `PATH` in your `~/.profile` like so

Open a the file in your home directory named `.profile`. If it doesnt exist create it with whatever text editor you prefer.

```sh
nano ~/.profile
```

Go to the end and add this

```
PATH="$HOME"/.local/bin:"$PATH"
```

If `$HOME` is not defined (`echo $HOME` should show your home directory) try replacing it with your username like

```
PATH=/home/trkornman/.local/bin:"$PATH"
```

You need to restart/relog after that to work.

Comment: `if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi`

Comment: In the comment in your question it looks like it doesn't exist. What does `echo $HOME` output?

Comment: Is it for sure `home/trkornman` and not `/home/trkornman`?

Comment: Ok there are 2 ways to find out what is going on. 1. Comment out that last if and add it explicitly like `PATH=/home/trkornman/.local/bin:$PATH`. 2. Add a second variable for testing, say `TRKORNMAN_TEST=1` at the end of `~/.profile` and re log in. Open terminal and do `echo $PATH` and `echo $TRKORNMAN_TEST` (should print 1). Looks like your system ignores `~/.profile`.

Comment: `if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH=/home/trkornman/.local/bin:$PATH
fi`
like this?

or like this, because otherwise $PATH stays red:

`if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH=/home/trkornman/.local/bin:"$PATH"
fi`